# Immersive mode locking app on Nexus Tablet

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, nexus-7, nexus-10

I just ran in to to an issue with immersive mode locking my app when testing on a android tablet (nexus7).

The only way to exit the lock was to swipe up to get back the software navigation bar and exit immersive mode.

How do I prevent this? What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue only appears when trying to enter immersive mode on a non-owner account. Android tablets support multiple users but apperently only one of them is considered "owner"  According to issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62366 the problem is known by google but no fix as of yet.

The problem is that the helpscreen that pops up is hidden/invisble but is still receiving the touchevents. It can be removed by clicking in the correct location but it can be somewhat tricky to find it when you have no visual clues as to where to click.

Hope this helps save someones time!